# Notepad++ 6.5.5 Auto Correct

Tags: notepad++

I just recently downloaded Notepad++ version 6.5.5 and it had an auto complete feature similar to Dreamweaver. I wanted to know how to remove this because it is just terrible. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion -> Enable auto-completion on each input (disable checkbox)